# Why is exclusive breastfeeding recommended for 6 months only?

Tags: human-biology, nutrition, literature

The [WHO](https://www.who.int/nutrition/topics/exclusive_breastfeeding/en/) recommends exclusive breastfeeding for the first 6 months of a child's life.

> Review of evidence has shown that, on a population basis, exclusive breastfeeding for 6 months is the optimal way of feeding infants. Thereafter infants should receive complementary foods with continued breastfeeding up to 2 years of age or beyond.

Their website mentions "review of evidence", but what is that evidence? Why 6 months and not 4 or 5 or 7 or 8 or 9 or anything like that?

Can anyone give which review is WHO talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess [this](https://www.who.int/nutrition/publications/infantfeeding/WHO_NHD_01.08/en/) is the review (ISBN: 92 4 156211 0) that they are referring to.

> We found no objective evidence of a “weanling’s dilemma.” Infants who
>   are exclusively breastfed for 6 months experience less morbidity from
>   gastrointestinal infection than those who are mixed breastfed as of 3
>   or 4 months, and no deficits have been demonstrated in growth among
>   infants from either developing or developed countries who are
>   exclusively breastfed for 6 months. Moreover, the mothers of such
>   infants have more prolonged lactational amenorrhea. Although infants
>   should still be managed individually so that insufficient growth or
>   other adverse outcomes are not ignored and appropriate interventions
>   are provided, the available evidence demonstrates no apparent risks in
>   recommending, as public health policy, exclusive breastfeeding for the
>   first6 months of life in both developing and developed country
>   settings. Large randomized trials are recommended in both types of
>   setting to rule out small adverse effects on growth and to confirm the
>   reported health benefits of exclusive breastfeeding for 6 months.

However, [another report](https://www.who.int/nutrition/publications/infantfeeding/9241562110/en/) suggests that exclusive breastfeeding for a long time may lead to deficiency of some nutrients which cannot be supplemented via maternal diet.

> The dual dependency on exogenous dietary sources and endogenous stores
>   to meet requirements needs to be borne in mind particularly when
>   assessing the adequacy of iron and zinc in human milk. Human milk,
>   which is a poor source of iron and zinc, cannot be altered by maternal
>   supplementation with these two nutrients. It is clear that the
>   estimated iron requirements of infants cannot be met by human milk
>   alone at any stage of infancy. The iron endowment at birth meets the
>   iron needs of the breastfed infant in the first half of infancy,i.e. 0
>   to 6 months. If an exogenous source of iron is not provided,
>   exclusively breastfed infants are at risk of becoming iron deficient
>   during the second half of infancy. Net zinc absorption from human milk
>   falls short of zinc needs, which appear to be subsidized by prenatal
>   stores.

Both these reviews are from WHO website; you can search for different [WHO research materials](https://www.who.int/nutrition/publications/research/en/) on the site.

***Note***: WHO **does not** say that breastfeeding should not be continued till a later stage. As noted in the review, **exclusive breastfeeding** for more than six months can cause some nutritional deficiencies. However, reducing **exclusive breastfeeding** to 3-4 months can reduce the immunity of the infant.

Comment: So basically they found the optimal time for exclusive breast feeding was between 4-6 months. I wonder what reason they listed 6 instead of the range?.

Comment: @John In such studies it is difficult to make fine measurements. Perhaps they just tried with 4 & 6 and didn't check other durations.

Comment: I liked the answer, but now I really want it to change, WHO should not make vague guidelines without sufficient data.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel WHO is trying to do best with whatever data they have. Note that whatever they say is a recommendation and general guideline. It is always better to consult a doctor for specific cases.

Comment: I am a medical student myself, and the part is doctor here dont see it as guidelines but as sacred stone line.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel exactly